# calling selector for a gesture recognizer in another class via delegation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom view that uses a gesture recognizer that calls a method `handleSingleTap`. This works fine if the setup for the gesture recognizer and the selector it calls are in the same custom view (CircleView).However, I need the `handleSingleTap` method in the viewController, so I (1) created a protocol in the custom view (CircleView), (2) created the delegate property in the view, and when I (3)created the gesture recognizer, I set `self.delegate` for the target of `handleSingleTap` (rather than just `self` as it was initially).  In the viewController.h, (4) I said that it conformed to the protocol and declared the method `handleSingleTap`. In the .m file of the view controller, I created a property for the custom view (CircleView) and then in viewDidLoad of the .m file, set `self` to be the delegate of the custom view. However, the `handleSingleTap` method is never getting called in the viewController when I tap on the circle in the custom view.

Can you explain why the selector `handleSingleTap` is not getting called in the viewController?

1) created protocol

```
@protocol CircleViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) tapper;

@end
```

2) created delegate property

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CircleViewDelegate> delegate;
```

in CircleView
3) created gesture recognizer with target `self.delegate`

```
-(void)setUpGestureRecognizers{

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap]; 
}
```

4) in the viewController.h,

```
   @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, CircleViewDelegate>
    -(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) tapper;
```

in the viewController.m

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CircleView *overlay;
```

viewDidLoad

```
self.overlay.delegate = self;
```

This method in the viewController is not getting called

```
-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) tapper {
     NSLog(@"never getting called");

}
```

Comment: Did you enable user interaction on your `overlay`? And, when do you call `setUpGestureRecognizers`? Where do you add your `overlay`? If you create your `overlay`, and calling `setUpGestureRecognizers` in `init` method of your `CircleView`, then of course it won't be called because, you are setting the delegate after you set gestures.

Comment: Are you actually calling `setUpGestureRecognizers`?

Comment: @dasdom Delegates should always be weak.

Comment: @nhgrif yes, setUpGestureRecognizers gets called, that's what the first sentence of the OP is supposed to imply (i.e everything works until I move the handleSingleTap method into the viewController)

Comment: @FahriAzimov userinteraction isn't an issue (see the new second and third sentence of the OP - everything works fine until I move the selector into the view Controller). But yes, I call setUpGestureRecognizers in the init of my CircleView, so I guess I am setting the delegate after I set the gestures

Comment: @dasdom it's not nil in viewDidAppear (i set it in viewDidLoad, and did a log check in viewDidAppear). Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: no notification is not the best solution.

Comment: @Leahcim Could be more clear if you showed how & when you're calling `setUpGestureRecognizers` since you included code for everything but that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution for you. Of course you can do it with Selectors too, but this will work for sure too.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CircleViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void) circleViewPressedByOneTap;

@end

@interface CircleView : UIView

@property (nonatomic,assign) id<CircleViewDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andWithDelegate:(id<CircleViewDelegate>)del;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "CircleView.h"

@interface CircleView () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@end

@implementation CircleView

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andWithDelegate:(id<CircleViewDelegate>)del
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        delegate = del;
        [self setUpGestureRecognizers];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setUpGestureRecognizers{

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    singleFingerTap.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
}

-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) tapper{
    [delegate circleViewPressedByOneTap];
}
```

And in your ViewController .m:

```
#import "YouClassViewController.h"
#import "CircleView.h"

@interface YouClassViewController () <CircleViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation YouClassViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    CircleView* yourCircleView = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50) andWithDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:yourCircleView];
}

- (void) circleViewPressedByOneTap{
    NSLog(@"Yeaah you pressed it ! :) ");
}
```

Comment: Delegate MUST be assign, or weak property, because it will cause a memory retain cycle... It's not unsafe, you should use it like that.

Comment: If you have code with strong delegates, I think you have to read about some memory management.

Comment: @incmiko No one is recommending the delegate be `strong`.  The recommendation is for `weak` rather than `assign`.  When the object an `assign` property references is deallocated, you can now potentially call a method on a deallocated object, which results in a crash.  Weak properties will not cause a retain cycle, but when the object they points to is deallocated, the weak property is automatically set to `nil`, so there's no possible way to call a method on a deallocated object if you use `weak`.  You should really only use `assign` for primitive data type properties.

Comment: @dasdom If you are using `strong` for delegate properties, you've got a design flaw in your program.  If object A is the delegate, object B should have a weak reference to it and object B should only need to exist if A exists.  Something else should hold the strong reference to Object A.  And then when that something else let's go of A, then both A and B can deallocate.

Comment: @nhgrif yes you are right in ARC, weak reference should be the right way, but in non arc, there isn't weak, there is only assign, and yes if you are using assign you have to care about these assigned delegates, to make sure your program won't get crash.

Comment: @dasdom if you use strong reference for delegates, you don't know enough about memory management

Comment: Given that the original question is already using `weak` references, don't you think your answer should use `weak` as well rather than potentially misleading someone using ARC to use the unsafe `assign` when they could/should use `weak`?